# SAPUI5 - Login Page

Tags: html, json, rest, sapui5, maximo

I'm building an app that communicates with an IBM software through REST. 
The thing is that I have a POST Method in the NewTicket.controller, but I need to use the user and password on this method to open the ticket. 
How can I send the variables (or other thing) that I have on my Login.controller to the NewTicket.controller?

This is my Post Method:

```
enviar:function() {
        var description = this.byId("desc").getValue(); //Recebe o resumo
        var long_description = this.byId("long_desc").getValue(); //Recebe a descrição
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageToast");
        sap.m.MessageToast.show(user);
        jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");
        // open a fully configured message box
        sap.m.MessageBox.show("Confirmar a abertura do chamado?",
                sap.m.MessageBox.Icon.QUESTION,
                "Confirmar",
                [sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES, sap.m.MessageBox.Action.NO], 
                function(sResult) {
            if(sResult == sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES)    //Se clicar em SIM (popup com numero do chamado e tela com lista) 
            {
                var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                var url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx/maxrest/rest/mbo/sr/?_lid=" + **user** + "&_lpwd=" + **password** +"&description="+ description +"&description_longdescription=" + long_description + "&_format=json&_compact=true&_verbose=true";
                var aData = jQuery.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    url : url,
                    dataType : "json",
                    async: false, 
                    success : function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        oModel.setData({modelData : data}); 
                        sap.m.MessageBox.show("ABRIU");
                    },
                    error : function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        oModel.setData({modelData : data}); 
                        sap.m.MessageBox.show(textStatus);
                    }
            })}
            else  // Se clicar em NÃO
           {
           }
        },
                sap.m.MessageBox.Action.YES);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
        </script>
        <script>
                sap.ui.localResources("app");
                var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"idinitial1"});
                var page = sap.ui.view({id:"loginPage", viewName:"app.login", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
                app.addPage(page);
                app.placeAt("content");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**login.view.xml**

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
        controllerName="app.login" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page title="Title">
        <content>
            <Panel headerText = "example" expandable = "true" expanded = "true">
              <content>  
                  <Input id="userID" value="User123"/>
                  <Button text="Login" press="btnClicked"/>
             </content>
             </Panel>
        </content>
    </Page>
</core:View>
```

**login.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.controller("app.login", {
    btnClicked: function(){
        this.userName = this.byId('userID').getValue();
        //loading the second view but not placed anywhere, just for showing code usage
        sap.ui.view({id:"myTickePage", viewName:"app.ticket", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
    }
});
```

**ticket.view.xml can be anything but inside ticket.controller.js:**

```
onInit: function() {
        var user = sap.ui.getCore().byId('loginPage').getController().userName;
        console.log(user);
    },
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Im getting a "Error: failed to load 'NewTicket.view.js' from resources/NewTicket.view.js: 404 - error". This is my btnClicket function: this.userName = this.byId('userID').getValue();
          //loading the second view but not placed anywhere, just for showing code usage
          sap.ui.view({id:"myTickePage", viewName:"NewTicket", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
  var router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
  router.navTo("MainPage");

Comment: Changed the View Type to sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML and its not working

Comment: Error: resource NewTicket.view.xml could not be loaded from resources/NewTicket.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors.

Comment: this looks like a path error. I have used 'app.login' as viewName because my login.view.xml is within the folder 'app' within the webcontent. In your cases its unable to locate your view.

Comment: Now my problem is that undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sap.ui.getCore().byId("loginPage").getController'). I don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: This means there is no control with id 'loginPage'

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable under the controller scope of Login.controller.
Eg: In Login.controller have a variable `this.myValue`

In MyTicket.controller:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId('loginViewID').getController().myValue
```

This will work as long as your login view/controller are not destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose two views:

1. login view corresponding to Login.controller (viewid_login)
2. ticket view corresponding to NewTicket.controller (viewid_ticket)

**In Login.controller:**

```
onInit: function() {
        this.userName= "User123";
    },
```

**In NewTicket.controller:**

```
onInit: function() {
        var user = sap.ui.getCore().byId('viewid_login').getController().userName;
//this will return "User123"
        },
```

Hope this makes it clear.
Note that your login view should not be destroyed.

Comment: The point is that I can't set the username like this, I'll receive it from the keyboard.. So, can I use on the view something like a **"this.byId("user").getValue();"**??

Comment: This will work as long as you are within the controller of the view holding the control whose id is 'user'. But wont work in other controllers or other JsViews

Comment: But, as I said, i need to use the user and password on the Post Method, that is on the NewTicket controller... Is that possible?

Comment: Use: sap.ui.getCore().byId('user').getValue(). Make sure the id you use is the same as DOM id.

Comment: My login view is like this:  <Input type="Text" design="bold" id="user"/>.        My login controller: onInit: function() {this.userName = sap.ui.getCore().byId("user").getValue(); }                                                          My new ticket controller: var user = sap.ui.getCore().byId("loginPage").getController().userName;                      Its not working yet...

Comment: Your input control id is 'user' but when the view is rendered does the id remain same? It might be having the view id prefix eg: loginPage-user. Please use your DOM id, ie the rendered id.

Comment: Sorry, but idk what is DOM id

Comment: When you inspect element in the browser in debugging mode. You will see the id allocated to the rendered control. Eg: <div id="**loginPage--user**"....>...</...

Comment: Got it. My id is: "__xmlview4--user-inner". I put it on the NewTicket.controller like this: var user = this.byId("__xmlview4--user-inner").getController().userName; And I'm getting a "[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.byId("__xmlview4--user-inner").getController')"

Comment: Since this is generated id, it may not always be the same and your code will fail when you hardcode the generated id. Have posted another answer with all the required code and the working output. Hope it helps.Enjoy!!

Comment: this.byId("__xmlview4--user-inner").getController().userName... this is totally incorrect. You cannot have a controller for a div. getController() can be used only with view. Correct would be sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview4--user").getValue()...but i suggest do not use generated ids in your code

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you are storing the user and password. The correct way would be to actually store them in the model. Initialize the model on the onInit and then get them when you need them.

```
onInit: function() {
..
 var data = {user: 'bla', password: 'ble'};
 var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
 oModel.setData(data);
 sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
..
}
```

then on the view you can get the values with:

```
var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
var data = oModel.getData();
//data.password
//data.user
```

Comment: But if im storing in a model, how can I access them in the NewTicket.controller (that is not associated to the login.view)??

Comment: Models set to the core are global to all views / controllers etc.